# How to set a position of an element 5px below a fixed position element

Tags: javascript, css, html

Ex: the 1st Div:

```
<div style='position: fixed; width=100%'> ....</div>
```

Now i want to put another Div 5px right below the previous Div. So i did

```
<div style='padding-top:5px; width=100%'> ....</div>
```

But it didn't work, seem `padding-top` compare itself to the top of window but not to its previous Div. If i remove the `position: fixed;` in the 1st div then it will be fine, but i don't want that.

I want the 1st Div got position fixed & the 2nd Div's position is 5px right below the 1st one. So how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: fixed` removes the element from the regular flow. You can't use flow positioning anymore.

There are likely proper ways to do what you want, but I don't know what you want because you told us about Y, not X: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

---

I think I understand what you want. If you always know how high the header is you can just add an offset, padding and margin should both work.

```
<div id="header" style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 20px;">
<div id="content" style="margin-top: 20px;">Content goes here</div>
```

If the header can change height adjust your CSS so that the header and content change their height and content respectively.

```
<div id="container" class="adjustheaderheight">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="content">Content goes here</div>
</div>

#header { position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 20px; }
#content { margin-top: 20px; }
#container.adjustheaderheight #header {
    height: 40px;
}
#container.adjustheaderheight #content {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

If your header changes height dynamically you'll need to change the content offset dynamically although I would strongly advise you not to have a dynamic header.

Comment: I want a fixed header & other elements go below that fixed header. that's simple

Comment: So we have to update the offset manually when the 1st Div got higher? 
is that the only solution? no other solution?

Comment: will ur solution works ok in all browsers if we have to manually measure the height of the 1st Div by ourself?

Comment: Yes, you must update it manually since `position: fixed` breaks the flow. This solution probably works in all browsers, I remember position fixed being broken in IE6 but nobody uses that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

put the two divs in a wrapper posioned fixed. Also you have invalid css syntax width=100% must be width:100%.

```
<div style="position: fixed;">
   <div style=' width:100%'> ....</div>
   <div style='margin-top:5px; width:100%'> ....</div>
</div>
```

however, this makes the 2 divs fixed... and this might not be what you want. You could do the following:

```
    <div style='position: fixed; width:100%'> ....</div>
   <div style='position:absolute; width:300px;height:200px;top:300px;left:300px'> ....</div>
```

css values are just for example...

> UPDATE:

is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/K8N4f/1/

```
<div id="fixed">fixed</div>
<div id="widget" >content <br>hjgjhgjhgjhgh</div>

#fixed{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background:yellow;
    height:50px;
    z-index:2;
}
#widget{

    background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    top:55px;
    margin-top:15px;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: no, i want the 1st Div got fixed & the 2nd Div can have height based on the widget inside it. So when 2nd Div has more content, then i can scroll to se the content while stil see the 1st Div

Comment: similar to  Frits van Campen's solution as i have to update the position manually when changing the height of the header

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried margin-top instead?
`margin-top: 5px`

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna include both these divisions within another division and make this new outer division position fixed. Like this --->

```
<div style='position: fixed; width=100%'>
  <div style='width=100%'> ....</div>
  <div style='padding-top:5px; width=100%'> ....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i don't want the 2nd Div got fixed

Comment: The answer above(the first answer in the thread) is perfect solution to your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried Margin and it doesn't work feel free to use padding as long as you don't have a background color or image within the div then you won't be able to tell the difference between the two ways of doing this.